# XML Query Namespace & Node

Tags: xml, web-services, xpath, soap

I wish to write an XPath query to my XML Query Function. I am running into an issue primarily based in my lack of previous knowledge of anything XML and I've been forced into it a bit.

But let's say I have a text box with the following XML output, how would I pull the information from say the `<State>` of the `<ShipmentOrigin>`? Mind you, there are a few other instances of `<State>`, so doing a full out search for `<State>` won't work, it would have to be specifically focused on the `<State>` within `<ShipmentOrigin>`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <TrackViaPronumberAdvancedResponse xmlns="https://webservices.rrts.com/tracking/">
            <TrackViaPronumberAdvancedResult>
                <ShipmentOrigin>
                    <Name>EXAMPLE</Name>
                    <Address1>EXAMPLE</Address1>
                    <Address2>EXAMPLE</Address2>
                    <City>EXAMPLE</City>
                    <State>EXAMPLE</State>
                    <PostalCode>EXAMPLE</PostalCode>
                </ShipmentOrigin>
                <ShipmentDestination>
                    <Name>EXAMPLE</Name>
                    <Address1>EXAMPLE</Address1>
                    <Address2/>
                    <City>EXAMPLE</City>
                    <State>EXAMPLE</State>
                    <PostalCode>EXAMPLE</PostalCode>
                </ShipmentDestination>
                <Details>
                    <Pronumber>EXAMPLE</Pronumber>
                    <PickupNumber/>
                    <CustomerNumber>EXAMPLE</CustomerNumber>
                    <BOLNumber/>
                    <PONumber>EXAMPLE</PONumber>
                    <Pieces>5</Pieces>
                    <Weight>214</Weight>
                    <AppointmentDate>9/20/2017</AppointmentDate>
                    <EstimatedDelivery>NA</EstimatedDelivery>
                    <DeliveredDate>9/20/2017</DeliveredDate>
                    <BillToNumber>5001868</BillToNumber>
                    <AppointmentTime>10:00 AM</AppointmentTime>
                    <ProjectedDeliveryDate>2017-09-25T00:00:00</ProjectedDeliveryDate>
                    <DeliveredTime/>
                    <HAWB/>
                </Details>

                <OriginTerminal>
                    <TerminalName>San Francisco</TerminalName>
                    <TerminalTollFreePhone>(877) 220-4582</TerminalTollFreePhone>
                </OriginTerminal>
                <Comments>
                    <ShipmentComment>
                        <CommentDate>09/14</CommentDate>
                        <ActivityCode>PU</ActivityCode>
                        <Comment>Shipment was picked up</Comment>
                        <StatusTime>12:03 AM</StatusTime>
                    </ShipmentComment>
                    <ShipmentComment>
                        <CommentDate>09/25</CommentDate>
                        <ActivityCode>DUD</ActivityCode>
                        <Comment>Projected Delivery Date of 9/25/2017</Comment>
                        <StatusTime>12:03 AM</StatusTime>
                    </ShipmentComment>
                    <ShipmentComment>
                        <CommentDate>09/16</CommentDate>
                        <ActivityCode>CLO</ActivityCode>
                        <Comment>Trailer Closed - ready for dispatch</Comment>
                        <StatusTime>2:00 AM</StatusTime>
                    </ShipmentComment>
                    <ShipmentComment>
                        <CommentDate>09/17</CommentDate>
                        <ActivityCode>DSP</ActivityCode>
                        <Comment>Trailer dispatched to terminal</Comment>
                        <StatusTime>12:00 PM</StatusTime>
                    </ShipmentComment>
                    <ShipmentComment>
                        <CommentDate>09/18</CommentDate>
                        <ActivityCode>ENR</ActivityCode>
                        <Comment>Trailer enroute: BRYAN, WY</Comment>
                        <StatusTime>3:02 PM</StatusTime>
                    </ShipmentComment>
                    <ShipmentComment>
                        <CommentDate>09/19</CommentDate>
                        <ActivityCode>INV</ActivityCode>
                        <Comment>Invoice has been emailed</Comment>
                        <StatusTime>6:03 AM</StatusTime>
                    </ShipmentComment>
                    <ShipmentComment>
                        <CommentDate>09/19</CommentDate>
                        <ActivityCode>ARX</ActivityCode>
                        <Comment>Trailer arrived at terminal in DENVER, CO</Comment>
                        <StatusTime>12:00 PM</StatusTime>
                    </ShipmentComment>
                    <ShipmentComment>
                        <CommentDate>09/19</CommentDate>
                        <ActivityCode>UNL</ActivityCode>
                        <Comment>Trailer unloaded at terminal</Comment>
                        <StatusTime>12:01 PM</StatusTime>
                    </ShipmentComment>
                    <ShipmentComment>
                        <CommentDate>09/19</CommentDate>
                        <ActivityCode>TRF</ActivityCode>
                        <Comment>Released to Delivery</Comment>
                        <StatusTime>5:00 PM</StatusTime>
                    </ShipmentComment>
                    <ShipmentComment>
                        <CommentDate>09/20</CommentDate>
                        <ActivityCode>OFD</ActivityCode>
                        <Comment>Shipment out for delivery</Comment>
                        <StatusTime>12:00 PM</StatusTime>
                    </ShipmentComment>
                    <ShipmentComment>
                        <CommentDate>09/20</CommentDate>
                        <ActivityCode>APT</ActivityCode>
                        <Comment>Appointment set for delivery to consignee on 9/20/2017</Comment>
                        <StatusTime>1:03 PM</StatusTime>
                    </ShipmentComment>
                    <ShipmentComment>
                        <CommentDate>09/20</CommentDate>
                        <ActivityCode>DED</ActivityCode>
                        <Comment>Shipment delivered to consignee</Comment>
                        <StatusTime>4:05 PM</StatusTime>
                    </ShipmentComment>
                </Comments>
                <BOLReceived>true</BOLReceived>
                <PODReceived>true</PODReceived>
                <InspectionAvailable>false</InspectionAvailable>
            </TrackViaPronumberAdvancedResult>
        </TrackViaPronumberAdvancedResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on what's processing the XPath and whether or not you can bind a namespace to a prefix.

If you can bind the `https://webservices.rrts.com/tracking/` namespace to a prefix (`tr` for example), you could do something like this...

```
//tr:ShipmentOrigin/tr:State
```

If you are unable to bind the namespace to a prefix, you could use `local-name()`...

```
//*[local-name()='ShipmentOrigin']/*[local-name()='State']
```

You could/should also use `namespace-uri()` to make sure you're matching exactly what you're intending to match...

```
//*[namespace-uri()='https://webservices.rrts.com/tracking/' and local-name()='ShipmentOrigin']/*[namespace-uri()='https://webservices.rrts.com/tracking/' and local-name()='State']
```

Comment: Or in XPath 2.0, `//*:ShipmentOrigin/*:State`